# Set token value in response header using express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am having trouble setting token into header. I read express.js 4 doc at

**http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.set**

and it stated like

```
res.set('token', 'kjhdkf89q37453lajjfq23');
```

Below are how I configure express.js

```
var restful_express = express(); restful_express.use(bodyParser());

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
    next();
}

restful_express.use(allowCrossDomain);

restful_express.listen(7788, function() {

});
```

How I sent response back

```
res.set('token', 'kjhdkf89q37453lajjfq23');

res.json({userid:"123123678"});
```

and when I retrieve using jQuery and the value I got are below:

```
$.post( $('#url').val() + "/login", {email:"abab@gmail.com"}).done(function( data, textStatus, request ) {

    console.log(data.userid);
    // 123123678

    console.log(textStatus);
    // success

    console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders()); 
    // Content-Type: application/json 

    console.log(request.getResponseHeader("token")); 
    // null

});
```

Appreciate any advice please. Thanks !

regards,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CORS, you need to also set [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) to let the browser know which custom headers it is allowed to access.

Comment: Do you mean I have to add this?  
  
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'token');  
  
I added but token still return null

Comment: Hi @mscdex, Thanks.
I have added this res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'token') and its work for me.